# Spring security oauth2 fails issuer validation after 30 seconds

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spring-webflux

In a reactive spring webflux service, I have the endpoints configured to be protected by OAuth2 resource server. When I first launch the server, it validates the Bearer tokens properly but after about 30 seconds, the exact same requests begin failing with the following error:

```
error="invalid_token"
error_description="This iss claim is not equal to the configured issuer"
error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
```

I've verified that the token is valid and that the `iss` claim appears to be the same as what is configured in `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri`. If this wasn't configured properly, then I would be getting no valid requests.

Upon closer inspection, I've found that the error stems from the `URL` comparison of the `iss` claim and the expected URL in that the `InetAddress.getAddress()` match for the first 30 seconds, but then do not match. This is using an Azure AD provider endpoint `https://sts.windows.net/{{tenantId}}/` and I've verified that the URL *strings* match, just not the internal addresses. What might be causing this and how can I validate tokens with valid issuers after the initial 30 seconds? Thanks.

For reference, here is my `SecurityWebFilterChain`:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().and()
            .and().build();
}
```

Gradle implementations included:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.0.RC1
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.1.0.RC1
org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:5.1.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.1.1.RELEASE
```

Comment: I can get around the issue by writing a custom `ReactiveJwtDecoder`, but that seems a bit overkill for what I would expect to be basic functionality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like this was entered as issue [`#6073`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6073) in spring-security and was resolved in [`c70b65c`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/c70b65c5df0e170a2d34d812b83db0b7bc71ea25). It's currently slated to be resolved in 5.1.2.RELEASE or 5.2.0.M1.

The solution committed changed the URL to a String which allowed for the equality check to be more reliable in addition to removing the blocking DNS lookup call.

Comment: I pulled my hair out on this for a week. This answer needs to be upvoted 1000 times.