# This iss claim is not equal to the configured issuer. Spring Security Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, jwt

I am using `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` and `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri` as part of securing spring boot APIs.

If I use the public URL in the issuer-uri I do not have any problem. But I would like to use internal(private) URL in the issuer-uri because I do not want this traffic to be public as the spring boot application and oauth provider both are in the same network.

**When I try to access this API through internet(public), I generate token using public URL there comes the problem**

I get the following error.. What should I do if I like to use the internal(private) URL to make the traffic between Spring boot<->OAuth provier through internal network?

```
Bearer error="invalid_token",
error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: 
This iss claim is not equal to the configured issuer", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050156/spring-security-oauth2-fails-issuer-validation-after-30-seconds